# Openshift Jenkins(2) -- docker: command not found

Tags: docker, jenkins, openshift

When using a jenkins pod provisioned by openshift.

Using a Jenkins file like below

```
node {
    def app
    stage('Clone repository') {
        checkout scm
    }    
    stage('Build image') {
        app = docker.build("showcase")
    }
    stage('Test image') {
        app.inside {
            sh 'echo "Tests passed"'
        }
    }
    stage('Push image') {
        docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'docker-hub-credentials') {
            app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
            app.push("latest")
        }
    }
}
```

Upon running a build I see the following

```
docker build -t showcase .
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/showcase-2/workspace@tmp/durable-018470ac/script.sh: line 2: docker: command not found
```

It appears that docker is not available on the jenkins image:

```
openshift/jenkins:2
```

Could some-one help me understand what I can do to make docker available?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install docker to your Jenkins. You can find a how-to over [here](https://getintodevops.com/blog/the-simple-way-to-run-docker-in-docker-for-ci). With the following Dockerfile code you can create your own Jenkins with Docker installed:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

USER root

RUN apt update && apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
RUN apt update && apt install -y docker-ce
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins
```

This won't work out of the box for openshift/jenkins, since it is based on RedHat, you will need to replace those `apt` commands. You might be able to find some hints on that [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/).